# Is "OnDelete" coming to the original Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I see by way of a quick Google search that the Entity Framework ***Core*** has a method called "OnDelete" which accepts an enumeration to set a specific <del>default</del> ON DELETE behavior. The closest equivalent method in Entity Framework is "WillCascadeOnDelete" which is a horribly rigid and unflexible method considering that there are 4 possible options that can be chosen for the equivalent SQL "ON DELETE" trigger.

So, the Framework Core get's it right but is it even available in the original Entity Framework?

This raises a more general question on the topic. What is the "general" roadmap regarding these technologies that are very similar. Are they diverging, converging, or running on separate but parallel tracks for the foreseeable future? Is method parity between the two technologies an aspiring goal or no?